# DataGrid itemsSource from Joined Tables in SQL Database using LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

i have these tables in my SQL Server Express database.[image: my DB Tables]

my aim is to join "**UserInfo**" table with "**RelCU**" table and display the result in a **wpf DataGrid**.

i tried these codes but got an error while running the project.

```
IQueryable<RelCU> Query =  from u in dbEntities.UserInfoes
                           join m in dbEntities.RelCUs
                           on u.UserID equals m.UserID into temp
                           from j in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select j;
DataGridRegisteredUsers.ItemsSource = Query;
```

**XAML:**

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridRegisteredUsers" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,-1,-1"
                                  FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Opacity="0.9" FontFamily="B Nazanin" FontSize="15">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=UserInfoes.UserID}" IsReadOnly="True"
                                                    Header="ID" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=UserInfoes.FirstName}"
                                                    Header="First Name" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=UserInfoes.LastName}"
                                                    Header="Last Name" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=RelCUs.Score}"
                                                    Header="Score" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=RelCUs.Status}"
                                                    Header="Status" />

                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

thanks!

Comment: What error displayed?

Comment: What error u r getting?

Comment: You are using `LEFT JOIN`, and `select j`, so `j` can be `null`

Comment: @EdiG. & visgu minhas : i got this error :An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `LEFT JOIN`, and `select j`, so `j` can be null  :

```
  IQueryable<RelCU> Query = from u in dbEntities.UserInfoes
                            join m in dbEntities.RelCUs
                            on u.UserID equals m.UserID into temp
                            from j in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new
                            {
                                ID=u.UserID, 
                                FirstName=u.FirstName,
                                LastName=u.LastName,
                                Score = j == null? 0 : j.Score,
                                Status = j == null? "" :j.Status
                            };
  DataGridRegisteredUsers.ItemsSource = Query;
```

**XAML:**

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridRegisteredUsers" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,-1,-1"
                              FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Opacity="0.9" FontFamily="B Nazanin" FontSize="15">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ID}" IsReadOnly="True"
                                                Header="ID" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"
                                                Header="First Name" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}"
                                                Header="Last Name" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Score}"
                                                Header="Score" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Status}"
                                                Header="Status" />

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```